# Making django app notify people at specific time

Tags: python, django, cron

> **Short description**

How can I make my app send notification to a list of people after an amount of time that an event has been created?

> **Long description**

My website allows Bob to put something he wants to sell online. Several persons see it and want to buy it. If after 6 hours nobody is interested in, the seller should be notified by email.

> Solution I found that I think dirty

Run crontab every minute to check the whole articles that people not interesed in. **Drawbacks**: not too accurate+scan the whole database+external to my app ...

Is there better solutions ?

Comment: I think you won't escape crontab. Is 1-min interval not too accurate for your requirements? If the user is already viewing a page you can fine-tune the updating with js and ajax requests (ebay bid style).

Comment: Have you checked http://engineering.hackerearth.com/2013/06/05/scheduling-emails-with-celery-in-django/? Also you don't have to scan the whole database if you have some sort of index.

Comment: @Wtower 1-min-interval is clearly not as accurate as a something that runs at exactly the wanted time. Actually I want my app to be able to behave the right way even when nobody is on it

Comment: @AlfonsoPérez `hackerearth` like that, a lot of work though (thought there a were a simpler solution)

Comment: I do not know your requirements so I can't see how this is 'clearly' for anyone else. Anyway take a look at https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/real-time/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cron/0.3.6

Essentially, You use django_cron in INSTALLED_APPS as

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_cron',)
```

Setup a cron job by creating a cron.py in your project root

```
class SixHourEmailUpdate(CronJobBase):
    code = 'six_hour_reminder_cron'
    schedule = Schedule( run_every_mins = 360 ) # 6 hours

    def do(self):
         # Your email sending
```

Also you will have to setup a cron job with something that will run every once in a while.

```
*/5 * * * * bash /home/tester/my_cron/cron.sh
```

The cron.sh inturn calls

```
python /home/tester/app/my_app/manage.py runcrons
```

More documentation here
http://django-cron.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sample_cron_configurations.html#run-at-times-feature

Comment: Wow, django_cron looks interesting. Good catch!

Comment: The only thing i can think ok that is possibly missing from this package is self sufficiency, Still needs the kick from cron outside of Django to run. Ah well

Answer (score 2):

As option 1, you could write [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management) that will be used by crontab.

The option 2(actually also related to cron work) is use Celery or similar tool(in your case I prefer option 1).

Please feel free to ask questions, and I'll updated my answer